# MySQL error "1265 Data truncated for columna 'contrasenia' during update"

Tags: mysql

I am receiving an error in MySQL and the error is "1265 Data truncated for 'contrasenia' column updating

Here is the DDL of the table in question:

```sql
create  database InicioSesion ;
use InicioSesion

create TABLE usuario_login(  
    usuario VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,  
    contrasenia  enum ( 'sha1' ));
```

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: No problem with this CREATE TABLE query. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a43569606d221691d1ea3735f9cc6728 The problem occures in some another code - provide it. PS. Write in English, please.

Comment: Please show us the `SELECT`.

Comment: A `sha1` has a size of `binary(40)`, but what other values than the `usuario` have? `varchar(20)` is smaller, even if its a utf8 character set.